# Why can't I use or between "int" and "float"?

Tags: python

```
number = int or float (input("enter a nimber: "))
if type(number) == float :
    print ("that's float")
elif type(number) == str :
    print ("that's str")
else:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print("even int")
    else:
        print("odd int")
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-represents-a-number-float-or-int

Comment: @HarunYilmaz "not to be used when defining variables" it *can* be, you just have to understand the semantics.

Comment: `input` always returns a string, if you want something else you need to convert it.

Comment: You’ll want a different approach.  I suggest getting the input as a string first and then using multiple `try` blocks (or a loop) to try converting it to an int and then a float.

Comment: ChatGPT has a perfectly nice explanation for this. Unfortunately I shall not post generated content. Maybe you try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`or` operator resolves to first truthy value, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) for details. You can check if value is truthy by converting it to boolean: `bool(int)` → `True` and `bool(float)` → `True`. Thus, as both `int` and `float` builtins are truthy, the `or` operator gives you which ever was listed first. In your case `int or float` always resolves to `int`:

```py
>>> int or float
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: While this is not wrong, I doubt that it helps OP achieve their goal.

Comment: If the goal is to understand why their code always returns integer, it might. If the goal is to get the code to working state, then the linked post has better explanation.